# SSRS breadcrum just breaks into multiple lines

Tags: ssrs-2012

This is a very annoying thing happening to the reports I am developing. The top breadcrumb sometimes works fine while at times breaks into multiple lines.  I have only IE 11 in my environment, Is it the browser issue? If not then please help me fix this.

Below is the screenshot.

[image: SSRS]

Comment: No it's not a Browser issues.

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan Any solution for this?

Comment: Could you provide bit specific more about your system configuration and also SQL Server .

Comment: SQL Server 2012 Enterprise and System has all high specs. I am still doubting my browser.

Comment: As per your screen shot it does not seems that you have browser IE11 issue. Suppose that you have "browser level" issue or "report server level" issue then you have to do troubleshooting.

Comment: It is IE 11.Yes I am doing my part but thought could get some help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFter days of scratching my head and google finally fixed with a vey simple setting. This was resolved by adding the url to the **Compatibility View Settings** in the IE browser settings.

[image: Fixed]

Answer (score 0):

As MSSQLTIPS blog documentation [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3666/sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-is-not-compatible-with-internet-explorer-11/) Sometimes when you change parameter values IE11 stops responding or it takes a long time to load the report. You may also find that the toolbar that displays the report controls and export features, appears on multiple lines when viewed with IE11. When you preview the same SSRS report in Chrome or Mozilla Firefox, it works fine without any issue, which means it is a browser compatibility issue. How can you make SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) compatible with IE11?